# What does tf.get_operations actually return?

Tags: python, tensorflow, operation

*"[tf.get_operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_operations) return the list of operations in the graph.*

*You can modify the operations in place, but modifications to the list such as inserts/delete have no effect on the list of operations known to the graph.
This method may be called concurrently from multiple threads.*

*Returns:
A list of Operations."*

Can anyone give me an idiots guide to what this *actually* means please?

I know tf.Operations is an object which produces an output of a tensor, given an input of a tensor. I am guessing it reads these operation from the tensor graph then?

Printing the variable returned by `ops = get_operations()` produces a whole bunch of text like so, is this all from the frozen graph?

```
 <tf.Operation 'FirstStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/InceptionV2/Mixed_3c/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_3x3/Conv2D' type=Conv2D>, <tf.Operation 'FirstStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_3c/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma' type=Const>
```

Thanks.

Bonus :

```
all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
```

How does this work?

Comment: An [Operation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation) "Represents a graph node that performs computation on tensors.". `get_operations` returns the list of those Operations.  `print` just gives you the `repr` of that list. Your bonus question looks like it is asking about what is a set comprehension.